# How to create an after update trigger in oracle and how to use it in WPF C# application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, oracle, triggers

**Problem**

I have three tables in my oracle database namely-customer(which contains the details of the customers),AccountDetails (which contains the details of the account of the customer), and the Transaction table. Now what I want to do is create a trigger in oracle which executes after there is an update in AccountDetails (the operations being withdraw and deposit) and when the trigger executes it will enter the records in the transaction table.The fields in the transaction table are-
T_ID              NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
CUSTOMER_ID       NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
ACC_NO            NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
T_TYPE                     VARCHAR2(20)
T_AMOUNT                   NUMBER(20,2)
T_DATETIME                 DATE

now I am not able to figure out how to create trigger and insert values in the transaction table.
the values in the T_type column should be credit or debit based on the transaction and that can only be sent when i sent the values to insert from within those functions.But how?

**ViewModelCode**

```
private void Transactions(object obj)
        {
            Transactions tr = new Transactions();
            TransactionsViewModel trvm = new TransactionsViewModel(Id);
            tr.DataContext = trvm;
            tr.Show();
        }
private void Withdraw(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
                con.Open();
                OracleDataReader reader;
                cmd = new OracleCommand($"Select Acc_No,Balance from Account_Details where PIN='{Convert.ToInt32(Pin)}'", con);
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    if((Amount>0) && (Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(1))>Amount))
                    { 
                        cmd = new OracleCommand($"Update Account_Details SET Balance=Balance -'{Amount}' where Customer_ID='{Id}' and PIN='{Pin}'", con);
                        int n=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        if (n > 0)
                        {
                            cmd = new OracleCommand($"Select Balance from Account_Details where PIN='{Convert.ToInt32(Pin)}'", con);
                            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                            MessageBox.Show("Remaining Balance:" + reader.GetValue(0));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Insufficient balance");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect PIN");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());

            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }

        }
        private void Deposit(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
                con.Open();
                OracleDataReader reader;  
                if (Amount > 0 && Pin!=null) 
                { 
                    cmd = new OracleCommand($"Update Account_Details SET Balance=Balance +'{Amount}' where Customer_ID='{Id}' and PIN='{Pin}'", con);
                    int n=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if(n>0)
                    {
                       cmd = new OracleCommand($"Select Balance from Account_Details where PIN='{Convert.ToInt32(Pin)}'", con);
                       reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                       MessageBox.Show("Current Balance:" +reader.GetValue(0));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                      MessageBox.Show("Incorrect PIN");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid amount");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());

            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can I make some suggestions to improve your code?: make your conditions more like guard statements: check the "no good" condition and then exit the method early if it's met. It would make your code easier to read. You should also make use of `using` statements and have a local variable for the connection object. [Here's a sample of these changes](https://pastebin.pl/view/9f27e946). I'd also recommend using parameterized SQL queries, and that you use two separate OracleCommand variables. These suggestions aren't related to your problem, I just wanted to help improve your existing code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try to improve my code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the :NEW and :OLD values in the trigger to determine whether the balance has increased or decreased and assign T_TYPE dynamically.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER transaction_trg
AFTER UPDATE ON account_details
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_t_type varchar2(20);
BEGIN
  CASE 
    WHEN :old.balance > :new.balance THEN v_t_type := 'withdraw'
    WHEN :old.balance < :new.balance THEN v_t_type := 'deposit'
    ELSE v_t_type := 'none'
  END CASE;
  
  -- assuming that customer_id and acc_no are fields in the account_details 
  -- table (and are thus part of the transaction that fired the trigger)
  -- and that t_id is a number provided by a database sequence...

  IF v_t_type IN ('withdraw','deposit') THEN
    INSERT INTO TRANSACTION (T_ID, CUSTOMER_ID, ACC_NO, T_TYPE)
      VALUES (t_id_seq.nextval, :new.customer_id, :new.acc_no, v_t_type);
  END IF;

END transaction_trg;
/
```

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/database-triggers-overview

Comment: THEN v_t_type := 'Debit'
        amount=:old.balance - :new.balance
  THEN 
    v_t_type := 'Credit'
    amount=:new.balance - :old.balance
 i added a little code to the above for the amount but it is still showing error- invalid sql statement. please help @pmdba

Comment: amount := :old.balance - :new.balance this is the added line . it is still showing Success with compilation error

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my question :

```
  create or replace trigger Transaction_trg
    after update on Account_details
    for each row
    declare
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
    begin
     if(:New.Balance <> :Old.Balance) then
       if(:New.Balance < :old.Balance) then
       
        insert into transactions(T_ID,Customer_ID,Acc_No,T_Type,T_Amount,T_DateTime) values(TransactionId.nextval,:old.Customer_Id,:Old.Acc_No,'Debit',(:old.Balance-:New.Balance),sysdate);
        commit ;
        end if;
       if(:New.Balance > :old.Balance) then
        insert into transactions(T_ID,Customer_ID,Acc_No,T_Type,T_Amount,T_DateTime) values(TransactionId.nextval,:old.Customer_Id,:Old.Acc_No,'Credit',(:New.Balance-:OLd.Balance),sysdate);
        commit;
        end if;
    end if;
    end;
```

Comment: Do not put commits or autonomous_transaction in your trigger. Commits must come from the parent transaction or you will wind up with corrupted data if either the triggering transaction or your autonomous transaction are rolled back for any reason. The triggered insert should always be part of the same transaction as the insert on account_details.